# Error using blogdown serve_site

Tags: r, blogdown

I started building my website a few days ago. For some reason, I am getting a strange behavior with the function serve_site. After I close R studio, if I open again and run `blogdown:::serve_site()`, I dont get any error, but also Viewer window remains empty. I have no idea what it is going on, any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried opening the served site in your browser (there is a button within the viewer tab to do this)? Sometimes I have noticed the internal Rstudio viewer remains blank, but when I open in the browser it works fine.

Comment: @lewisjr2 Or refresh the RStudio Viewer (there is a refresh button on the right).

Comment: yep - works too, thanks :)

Comment: When I get this bug I dont have the option to refresh or open in the viewer. I realize it is always happen after I change some of the html file of the site. Now, I changed the single.html in the theme/publication/. Any other suggestion?