# blogdown 0.21 serve_site() no longer serves site

Tags: r, blogdown

After updating to 0.21 I ran rmarkdown::clean_site() then exited the R session. Started again and entered blogdown::serve_site() but the site was not created. Message:

> The site has been served under the directory "/home/dave/Documents/Cycling R files/cycs-universal". I have tried to reopen it for you with servr::browse_last(). If you do want to start a new server, you may stop existing servers with blogdown::stop_server(), or restart R. Normally you should not need to serve the same site multiple times in the same R session, otherwise you may run into issues like https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/404.

Tried blogdown::stop_server() but to no effect.

The html files are not created so I don't think it is this [viewer issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119912/error-using-blogdown-serve-site). In ver 0.20 I could run clean_site() and then serve_site() would build all the html files again. I wonder if I need to do something differently with 0.21 and have missed it but I have not been able to find anything.

```
xfun::session_info('blogdown')
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.2, RStudio 1.3.1073

Locale:
  LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8       
  LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
  LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
  LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 BH_1.72.0.3     blogdown_0.21   bookdown_0.21   digest_0.6.25  
  evaluate_0.14   glue_1.4.2      graphics_4.0.2  grDevices_4.0.2 highr_0.8      
  htmltools_0.5.0 httpuv_1.5.4    jsonlite_1.7.1  knitr_1.30      later_1.1.0.1  
  magrittr_1.5    markdown_1.1    methods_4.0.2   mime_0.9        promises_1.1.1 
  R6_2.4.1        Rcpp_1.0.5      rlang_0.4.8     rmarkdown_2.4   servr_0.19     
  stats_4.0.2     stringi_1.5.3   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.26    tools_4.0.2    
  utils_4.0.2     xfun_0.18       yaml_2.2.1
```

Comment: With **blogdown** 0.21, you no longer need to call `blogdown::serve_site()` explicitly in RStudio. See the fourth bullet in MAJOR CHANGES in the release notes: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/releases/tag/v0.21 You should see a message telling you that **blogdown** has started the server when you open the RStudio roject.

Comment: BTW, I don't know why you had to run `rmarkdown::clean_site()`, but if you meant to rebuild the whole site (i.e. recompile all R Markdown files), you will need `blogdown::build_site(build_rmd = TRUE)`. This is mentioned in the third bullet in NEW FEATURES.

Comment: Thank you resolved. Apologies for missing build_site(build_rmd=TRUE) in the release notes.

Comment: No worries at all! Good to know your issue has been resolved!

Comment: Hi, I hope I can ask this here, not sure it deserves a whole new post. Since the update, files in the "public" folder of my project haven't been updating. Is that intentional? Where are the updated HTML files kept now?

Comment: Hi mine are still updating in the "public" folder.