# Problem with rendering Hugo/blogdown site

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I've seen the post about [`blogdown::serve_site()` no longer serving the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343202/blogdown-0-21-serve-site-no-longer-serves-site) and read the release notes for blogdown 0.21, but it didn't help with my problem.

My workflow is/was to write a post, then click "Serve Site" in RStudio and check out the newly generated files in the public/ folder of my project. I have a symbolic link of that folder in my ShinyApps directory so I can view my site via the Shiny server. This is great, because then my colleagues who also use the server can see my site as well.
Now this doesn't work anymore. While I get the updated site in RStudio directly, the files displayed by the Shiny server are not being updated. The only explanation I can find is this one:

> The global option blogdown.generator.server has been deprecated. Now blogdown::serve_site() always use the Hugo server (which corresponds to options(blogdown.generator.server = TRUE) in previous version of blogdown), instead of the server created via the servr package (which corresponds to the default options(blogdown.generator.server = FALSE) before).

I don't know much about Hugo but I found that `hugo server` doesn't update the public/ directory, is that correct? What can I do now to update that?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/495

Comment: Thank you! That seems to cover all of my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was already [answered on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/495):
I need to build the site with `blogdown::build_site(local=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Turns out that the below was not the solution either for me. Therefore I posted an own question with a possible workaround:

[Problem (and solution?) with rendering Hugo/blogdown site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862070/problem-and-solution-with-rendering-hugo-blogdown-site)

---

**Earlier (old) post:**

With me this did not help. When updating **blogdown** and starting-up my R project, `blogdown:::preview_site(startup = TRUE)` automatically runs. Something I don't recall from earlier start-ups. I now always receive the same Error message:

> Launching the server via the command:
> hugo server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t hugo-academic -D -F --navigateToChanged
> sh: line 0: kill: (3262) - No such process
> Error: It took more than 30 seconds to launch the server. There may be something wrong. The process has been killed. If the site needs more time to be built and launched, set options(blogdown.server.timeout) to a larger value.

Running `blogdown::build_site(local = TRUE)` results in an even longer Error message starting with:

> ERROR 2020/11/13 15:55:56 render of "page" failed: execute of template failed: template: _default/single.html:6:5: executing "_default/single.html" at <partial "page_header.html" .>: error calling partial: execute of template failed: template: partials/page_header.html:92:7: executing "partials/page_header.html" at <partial "page_metadata" (dict "page" $page "is_list" 0 "share" true)>: error calling partial: "/Users/frederick/Dropbox/EUR/R_work/r_website/r_website_project/themes/hugo-academic/layouts/partials/page_metadata.html:63:31": execute of template failed: template: partials/page_metadata.html:63:31: executing "partials/page_metadata.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R

---

**Solution for me**
For me, it helped to roll-back to **blogdown** version `0.20` like so:

```r
packageVersion("blogdown")
#> [1] '0.21'

library("devtools")
#> Loading required package: usethis
install_version("blogdown", version = "0.20", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
#> Downloading package from url: http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/blogdown/blogdown_0.20.tar.gz

packageVersion("blogdown")
#> [1] '0.20'
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now everything is back to "normal".

Comment: Could this have anything to do with your theme? See "When creating a new site with blogdown::new_site(), the theme gcushen/hugo-academic is automatically redirected to wowchemy/starter-academic, because the original Github repo has moved and become a repo of Hugo modules." https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/releases

Comment: Yes that could be. Only I have no clue how to fix this.

Comment: You could file an issue in either the blogdown or hugo-academic repo, I guess. @Yihui is usually around to help, but I don't know how to tag him here.